# Why to_char function may change date in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I use `select value,datetime,to_char(sensortime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') datetime2 from test;`
I find datetime and datetime2 are different,How can I get the same result?
[image]

Comment: Please don't put images, copy the text to your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Why `to_char` function may change date in oracle

I does not change the date - it just changes how the date is formatted.

SQL/Plus and SQL Developer will typically use the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter to implicitly apply a format to a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Your query is effectively:

```
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         sensortime,
         (
           SELECT VALUE
           FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
           WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'
         )
       ) AS datetime,
       to_char(sensortime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') datetime2
FROM   test
```

Looking at the outputs, the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` is

```
'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SSxFF AM'
```

and your format is:

```
'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF'
```

Which is why they are giving different outputs (one is a 12--hour clock and the other is 24-hour clock).

> How can I get the same result?

Change your query to match the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT value,
       sensortime,
       TO_CHAR(sensortime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SSxFF AM') datetime2
FROM   test
```

Or change the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF'
```

and use your query.

Answer (score 1):

Change your session `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` as this:

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF';
```

In case data type of your column is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` you have to use `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` instead of `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`